# Complex conjugate for inner product

Tags: equations

I am having trouble writing an inner product with a horizontal bar over it representing the complex conjugate.

`$\langle b_i, b_j \rangle=\bar{\langle b_j, b_i \rangle}$` doesn't do the trick

Here [is an example](http://www.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf)

Regards

Comment: perhaps `\overline`

Comment: instad use a `*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use `\overline`. `\bar` is meant for a single character/symbol rather.

In order to switch the style later on I recommend a new macro (logical markup), say `\compconj` which wraps around `\overline` (or another command that does the 'complex conjugate' style)

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcommand{\compconj}[1]{%
  \overline{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
$\langle b_i, b_j \rangle=\compconj{\langle b_j, b_i \rangle}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would do it that way, using `mathtools` to define a variable-sized inner product:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\innerprod}\langle\rangle
\newcommand\conjinnerp[2][]{\:\overline{\mkern-4mu\innerprod[#1]{#2}\mkern-4mu}\:}

\begin{document}

\[ \innerprod{b_i, b_j } = \conjinnerp{b_j, b_i } = \cdots \]%

\[ \innerprod[\big]{b_i, b_j } = \conjinnerp[\big]{b_j, b_i } = \cdots \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]